# Android - SQLite - no such column error (greenDAO)

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I created my table structure with greenDAO and when updating the following table, I'm getting the follwing error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: BODY_LOG_ENTRY._id: ,
 while compiling: UPDATE BODY_LOG_ENTRY SET 
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY._id'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.FK_DAY'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.DAY_ORDER'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.DESCRIPTION'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.BODY_WEIGHT'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.BODY_SIZE'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.BODY_FAT_FORMULA'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA1'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA2'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA3'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA4'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA5'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA6'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA7'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA8'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA9'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.BODY_FAT'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.NECK'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.SHOULDER'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.CHEST'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.UNDERCHEST'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.WAIST'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.ARM_LEFT'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.ARM_RIGHT'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.FOREARM_LEFT'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.FOREARM_RIGHT'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.BUTT'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.THIGHES_LEFT'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.THIGHES_RIGHT'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.CALVES_LEFT'=?,
'BODY_LOG_ENTRY.CALVES_RIGHT'=? 
WHERE BODY_LOG_ENTRY.'_id'=?
```

- I already checked if all columns exist, and they do!
- I checked the names of the columns and they match
- I checked if a column name matches one keyword, but I did not find one (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

does anybody have any idea what the problem could be?

Following is the current create table query:

```
public static void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db, boolean ifNotExists) {
    String constraint = ifNotExists? "IF NOT EXISTS ": "";
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + constraint + "'BODY_LOG_ENTRY' (" + //
            " '_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + // 0: id
            " 'FK_DAY' INTEGER NOT NULL ," + // 1: fkDay
            " 'DAY_ORDER' INTEGER NOT NULL ," + // 2: dayOrder
            " 'DESCRIPTION' TEXT NOT NULL ," + // 3: description
            " 'BODY_WEIGHT' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 4: bodyWeight
            " 'BODY_SIZE' INTEGER NOT NULL ," + // 5: bodySize
            " 'BODY_FAT_FORMULA' INTEGER NOT NULL ," + // 6: bodyFatFormula
            " 'BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA1' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 7: bodyFatFormulaData1
            " 'BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA2' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 8: bodyFatFormulaData2
            " 'BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA3' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 9: bodyFatFormulaData3
            " 'BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA4' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 10: bodyFatFormulaData4
            " 'BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA5' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 11: bodyFatFormulaData5
            " 'BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA6' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 12: bodyFatFormulaData6
            " 'BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA7' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 13: bodyFatFormulaData7
            " 'BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA8' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 14: bodyFatFormulaData8
            " 'BODY_FAT_FORMULA_DATA9' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 15: bodyFatFormulaData9
            " 'BODY_FAT' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 16: bodyFat
            " 'NECK' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 17: neck
            " 'SHOULDER' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 18: shoulder
            " 'CHEST' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 19: chest
            " 'UNDERCHEST' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 20: underchest
            " 'WAIST' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 21: waist
            " 'ARM_LEFT' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 22: armLeft
            " 'ARM_RIGHT' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 23: armRight
            " 'FOREARM_LEFT' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 24: forearmLeft
            " 'FOREARM_RIGHT' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 25: forearmRight
            " 'BUTT' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 26: butt
            " 'THIGHES_LEFT' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 27: thighesLeft
            " 'THIGHES_RIGHT' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 28: thighesRight
            " 'CALVES_LEFT' REAL NOT NULL ," + // 29: calvesLeft
            " 'CALVES_RIGHT' REAL NOT NULL );"); // 30: calvesRight
    // Add Indexes
    db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX " + constraint + "IDX_BODY_LOG_ENTRY_FK_DAY ON BODY_LOG_ENTRY" +
            " (FK_DAY);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX " + constraint + "IDX_BODY_LOG_ENTRY_DAY_ORDER ON BODY_LOG_ENTRY" +
            " (DAY_ORDER);");
}
```

PS: all I can say is, that the table prefix should not be part of the update query, because without them, the query works... but the weird thing is, that all my other (>20) tables work... just this one does not

Comment: make sure you give a space while making the column in table

Comment: can you explain what you mean? I don't get what you want to say with that...

Comment: While you make a database table for example "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MAIN + "(" + KEY_ROW_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT (null) ,"+ KEY_DATETIME + " DATETIME ASCENDING ," + KEY_flag+ " INTEGER ," + KEY_celebid + " INTEGER "+ ")";

Comment: You can notice that there is a space at the starting and ending of the columns ( The one written in betweet " ")

Comment: I tried that, a space before and after EVERY column... unfortunately, that didn't not help

Comment: If you can post your code, that could help others to help you.

Comment: sure, added my create query to my question

Comment: thanks for the help though, found the solution... I just oversaw that I edited, for a manual select statement, all column names from the table... I forgot to clone the names before...

Comment: sorry could'nt help, glad you found a solution...

Answer (score 1):

When you update any fields, this updates don't refresh in the actual DB. A solution that worked for me, is delete all tables in the DB and then create all tables again. In my case, my database was empty.

See the next link: [How to clean/delete greenDao database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274187/how-to-clean-delete-greendao-database)

Other option is do ALTER TABLE on existing database.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem,you can try this :
check the table  which is a new table or a old table ,because we always create table with "if not exists".
PS:
 1.I am from China,my English is poor , Pray you can understand my words.
 2.the answer is for someone who will meet the same question after me.