# Green Dao insert not generating id

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I have a simple Model and I am inserting it into sqlite via GreenDao. Here is the model class:

```
@Entity
public class ImageModel implements Parcelable {

    public static final Creator<ImageModel> CREATOR = new Creator<ImageModel>() {
        @Override
        public ImageModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ImageModel(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ImageModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ImageModel[size];
        }
    };
    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private long id;
    private String downloadURL;
    private String pasteId;
    private String storageLocation;


    protected ImageModel(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readLong();
        downloadURL = in.readString();
        pasteId = in.readString();
        storageLocation = in.readString();
    }


    @Generated(hash = 345376828)
    public ImageModel(long id, String downloadURL, String pasteId,
                      String storageLocation) {
        this.id = id;
        this.downloadURL = downloadURL;
        this.pasteId = pasteId;
        this.storageLocation = storageLocation;
    }


    @Generated(hash = 799163379)
    public ImageModel() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ImageModel{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", downloadURL='" + downloadURL + '\'' +
                ", pasteId='" + pasteId + '\'' +
                ", storageLocation='" + storageLocation + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(id);
        dest.writeString(downloadURL);
        dest.writeString(pasteId);
        dest.writeString(storageLocation);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public String getDownloadURL() {
        return this.downloadURL;
    }

    public void setDownloadURL(String downloadURL) {
        this.downloadURL = downloadURL;
    }

    public String getPasteId() {
        return this.pasteId;
    }

    public void setPasteId(String pasteId) {
        this.pasteId = pasteId;
    }

    public String getStorageLocation() {
        return this.storageLocation;
    }

    public void setStorageLocation(String storageLocation) {
        this.storageLocation = storageLocation;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

I am trying to insert the instances of this ImageModel class via AbstractDao.insert() call, but the row id returned is always 0.

I have tried using `Long` instead of `long` for id field type as suggested in this github discussion:
https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/441

but this does not seems to work. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Do the following:

1. Change `long id` by `Long id` in all tables that id is autoincrement.
2. Delete all code generated by GreenDAO (in case that you don't use generator or you are using `@annotations` of GreenDAO 3), then CLEAN PROJECT.
3. Do `ALTER TABLE` to all tables with id autoincrement **OR** re-create all tables in this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32429968/5286400

If you  want, see the next link with a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44527501/5286400